# MvvmCross 6.4.1 not can be update with PCL project with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, portability

How do I solve the "Package MvvmCross 6.4.1 is not compatible" error? I am using NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44.

Here's the diagnostic logs:

```
Estou tentando atualizar o package do MvvmCross para o 6.4.1 em projeto PCL com o visual Studio for Mac:
*"Package MvvmCross 6.4.1 is not compatible with portable46-net451+win81 (.NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44). Package MvvmCross 6.4.1 supports"*

Visual Studio detials:
"Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.3.11 (build 1)
Installation UUID: 358942d8-ccc4-4e01-be4d-8b50089ff31c
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
Xamarin.Mac 5.16.1.24 (d16-3 / 08809f5b)

Package version: 604000208

Mono Framework MDK
Runtime:
Mono 6.4.0.208 (2019-06/07c23f2ca43) (64-bit)
Package version: 604000208

Xamarin Designer
Version: 16.3.0.256
Hash: 8a223bfd7
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3
Build date: 2019-11-01 21:02:02 UTC

NuGet
Version: 5.3.0.6192

.NET Core SDK
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.101/Sdks
SDK Versions:
3.0.101
3.0.100
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.4.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Core Runtime
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
3.0.1
3.0.0
2.1.14
2.1.13

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.6.12.29
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 11.2.1 (15526.1)
Build 11B53

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 6.6.0.12 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: e3c2b406d
Branch: xcode11.2
Build date: 2019-11-01 00:12:07-0400

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 13.6.0.12 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: e3c2b406d
Branch: xcode11.2
Build date: 2019-11-01 00:12:08-0400

Xamarin.Android
Not Installed

Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Users/iterative/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
1.8.0-25
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 1.4.0.65
Hash: c33b107
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3
Build date: 2019-11-19 20:33:22 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 1.2.0.116
Hash: d2b2af0
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3
Build date: 2019-11-19 20:33:42 UTC

Xamarin Inspector
Version: 1.4.3
Hash: db27525
Branch: 1.4-release
Build date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

Build Information
Release ID: 803110001
Git revision: 6ee6ad2ec46ae5a08a1999ee4c815ac656a35b91
Build date: 2019-12-05 16:09:27+00
Build branch: release-8.3
Xamarin extensions: 56bd70ef2e327f71c615cfc29a47fd50685fadcb

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.14.6
Darwin 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0
    Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019
    root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
```

Comment: Do your self a favor and migrate your PCL projects to dotnet standard. The tooling is stable and you only have advantages.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because the version of Nuget Package you are trying to add is Not Compatible with the target framework of your project. You have two options:

- You would have to either convert your project to use .NET Standard from PCL, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/net-standard). It can be painful if your solution is big and old. Personally I suggest starting from a blank .NET Standard project and bringing in items from your existing project instead one at a time.
- Or you have to use a lower version of MVVMCross.

I would suggest staying away from the second option though, because the lower MVVMCross package does not support Android Target Framework 10.0, and it will bite you in the distant future.